# ASP.NET Chart for Grades Distribution

Tags: asp.net, charts

I'd like to show an ASP.NET Chart control that shows a distribution of grades.

It should show how many students got which grade, ranging from A to F.

How do I make the chart include the grades A, B, C, D, F in the cases where no students got, say, a D letter grade? For example, I'd like the D value to to present on the X-axis, but with a student count of zero.

The data is being pulled from a database and I'm using an ObjectDataSource to bind to the chart control.

EDIT: The structure of the data is that there's a Students table and each stundent has a FirstName, LastName, and Grade.

EDIT: For the rest of the site I'm using Entity Framework with LINQ (as opposed to writing raw SQL), so, in a perfect world, the solution wouldn't involved raw SQL.

Comment: I edited the response below based on your edit to not use raw sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to change your query includes all grades then fill in the details for each grade?
total hack - but to show you the idea as I don't know your schema

```
select * from 
(
select 'a' Grade
union
select 'b' Grade
union
select 'c' Grade
union
select 'd' Grade
union
select 'f' Grade
) as grades g
outer join yourothertable t on g.Grade = t.Grade
```

Edit: After reading your edit realizing you don't want this to be a sql solution, then the choice is to take your objects and do a linq join on them to objects containing the grade.

see:
http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx
use something like 
public class Grade
{
    public string LetterGrade;
}
populate a list of them, and do an outer join to your results from your query. Your new linq results collection is what you now databind.

Answer (score 0):

Without know how your data is structured it's a bit difficult to give a detailed answer.  Here's a way to do it using SQL Common Table Expressions (CTEs). It will organize the data so that you can easily bind it to a chart control.

This will produce a table of data as follows:

```
| Grade | TotalGrades |
|-------|-------------| 
|   A   |      2      |
|   B   |      1      |
|   C   |      2      |
|   D   |      0      |
|   E   |      0      |
|   F   |      1      |
```

And here's the code:

```
;With Grades (Grade) as
(
    SELECT 'A' Grade
    UNION
    SELECT 'B' Grade
    UNION
    SELECT 'C' Grade
    UNION
    SELECT 'D' Grade
    UNION
    SELECT 'E' Grade
    UNION
    SELECT 'F' Grade
),
GradeResults (Name,Grade) as
(
    SELECT 'John','A'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Sally','B'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Dave','C'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Charlie','C'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Lisa','F'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Russ','A'
)
SELECT a.Grade, COUNT(b.Grade) as TotalGrades FROM Grades a LEFT OUTER JOIN GradeResults b on a.Grade = b.Grade
GROUP BY a.Grade
ORDER BY a.Grade;
```